# Tensorflow Object Detection - Avoid overlapping boxes

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection

Intro:
I'm new to machine learning and me and a colleague have to implement an algorithm for detecting traffic lights. I downloaded a pre trained model (faster rcnn) and ran several training steps (~10000). Now when using the object detection algorithm from the tensorflow git repository several traffic lights in one area are detected.

I did a little research and found the function "tf.image.non_max_suppression" but I cannot get it to work as intended (to be honest, I cannot even get it to run).

I assume you know the tf object detection sample code so you also know that all boxes are returned using a dictionary (output_dict).

To "clean" the boxes I use :

```
selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
        boxes           = output_dict['detection_boxes'],
        scores          = output_dict['detection_scores'],
        max_output_size = 1,
        iou_threshold   = 0.5,
        score_threshold = float('-inf'),
        name            = None)
```

At first I thought I could use selected_indices as a new list of boxes so I tried this:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image                      = image_np,
      boxes                      = selected_indices,
      classes                    = output_dict['detection_classes'],
      scores                     = output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index             = category_index,
      instance_masks             = output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates = True)
```

but when I noticed this wont work I found a required method: "tf.gather()". Then I ran the following code:

```
boxes = output_dict['detection_boxes']
selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
    boxes           = boxes,
    scores          = output_dict['detection_scores'],
    max_output_size = 1,
    iou_threshold   = 0.5,
    score_threshold = float('-inf'),
    name            = None)

selected_boxes = tf.gather(boxes, selected_indices)

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image                      = image_np,
      boxes                      = selected_boxes,
      classes                    = output_dict['detection_classes'],
      scores                     = output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index             = category_index,
      instance_masks             = output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates = True)
```

but not even that one works. I receive an AttributeError ('Tensor' object has no attribute 'tolist') in visualization_utils.py on Line 689.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like to get the boxes in the right format, you need to create a session and evaluate the tensor as follows:

```
suppressed = tf.image.non_max_suppression(output_dict['detection_boxes'], output_dict['detection_scores'], 5) # Replace 5 with max num desired boxes

sboxes = tf.gather(output_dict['detection_boxes'], suppressed)
sscores = tf.gather(output_dict['detection_scores'], suppressed)
sclasses = tf.gather(output_dict['detection_classes'], suppressed)

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    boxes = sboxes.eval()
    scores =sscores.eval()
    classes = sclasses.eval()

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      boxes,
      classes,
      scores,
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```